# How to find all methods in C# solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, .net-reflector

I need to list all methods name and their unit tests in a C# solution/project.

Do you have any ideas on this?

Update: Do you know any C# source parser?

Comment: How should a tool know how methods and unit tests are related?

Comment: Why do you need that information? How do you want to use it?

Comment: I need to verify unit tests of a method are strong enough?
I wonder if developer just code unit test to fully coverage but Assert something nonsense like Assert.IsTrue(true). So I try to modify source code by removing code path, modify constants, build solution and run unit tests again, if there're any unit tests always pass, then the unit test is "weak".

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need code coverage tool, which analyzes your solution and shows which lines of code tested and which are not. Take a look on [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/), [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/) or [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/).

Keep in mind, that simply finding unit test names for some method is not enough, because method may have many code execution paths inside, and some of them could be not covered with tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to find all methods (`Assembly.GetTypes()` returns all types, `type.GetMethods()` returns its methods). Since unit tests are programs as well, you can iterate through the unit test methods by looking for a `[TestMethodAttribute]` (depending on what test framework you're using) with `method.GetCustomAttributes()`.

Finding out what each test method does is alot harder though, since you have no restriction to what your test contains. A code coverage tool can show you exactly what parts of your code are tested, even the parts *inside* each method (what branches of `if` statements are covered, for example).

Comment: I need to find method in source code, not in MSIL because I want to modify some code in source. Just some minor modification like changing constants. It  overhead to modify in MSIL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a window in visual studios called "Resource view" it will enumerate all classes and methods in a treeview structure then when selected will bring the cursor to the file/line in question.